# Not found Api rest Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

He creado una aplicación rest con spring boot pero cuando la intento lanzar desde el soap siempre me devuelve esto.

```
 {
   "timestamp": "2021-12-28T12:11:17.389+00:00",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "path": "/demo/prueba"
 }
```

La aplicación siempre la arranco desde esta clase:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
 }
```

la clase controller es esta:

```
@RestController
    public class ApiTablasGenerales {


    
    @GetMapping("prueba")
    public List<String> findAll(){
        List<String> palabrabas = new ArrayList();
        palabrabas.add("AAsdsa");
        palabrabas.add("AA");
        palabrabas.add("AA");
        palabrabas.add("AA");
        palabrabas.add("AA");
        //retornará todos los usuarios
        return palabrabas;
    }
}
```

El endpoint del soap UI es esta:  `http://localhost:8081/demo/prueba`

Añado el proyecto https://github.com/borja13/demospring

¿Sabéis cual puede ser el fallo?

Comment: No tengo tanta cancha con el SOAP pero revisaría el `"path": "/demo/prueba"` del error, tal vez no estas colocando en la herramienta el baseurl y solo estas apuntando al endpoint. Por si no me explico deberías estar pegandole a un puerto del _localhost_ (ej: http://localhost:8080/demo/prueba). 
Esto hace sentido con el code 404 que no encuentra la ruta que especificas en la herramienta

Comment: sisi, he lanzado en el endpoint del soap ui lo de localhost:8080

Comment: Sin ver el fichero application.yml no estoy seguro, pero con la información que das probaría a ver si la URL es localhost:8081/prueba, sin /demo

Comment: En mi caso es application.properties y no tengo nada añadido. La ruta sin /demo no la encuentra tampoco

Comment: Prueba a añadirle el "/" en el `@GetMapping("/prueba")`, por otro lado si no has puesto contextPath el /demo no te hace falta

Comment: tampoco parece que funcione...

Comment: Puedes probar a añadir la anotacion @RequestMapping("/demo") en tu controller (debajo de @RestController por ejemplo) y a añadir la barra '/' delante de tu anotacion @GetMapping("prueba"), quedando así: @GetMapping("/prueba"). Veo tambien que lanzas contra el puerto 8081 (*http://localhost:8081/demo/prueba*), asegurate que cuando se haya levantado el servicio lo haya hecho en ese puerto, ya que spring boot levanta por defecto en el 8080